# How to add methods to custom object

Tags: c#, object, methods

I am making a game. I have an object I created called "Player". The Player class looks like this:

```
public class Player
{
    public Vector2 pos;
    public Rectangle hitbox;
    public Rectangle leftHitbox;
    public Rectangle topHitbox;
    public Rectangle bottomHitbox;
    public Rectangle rightHitbox; 
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Vector2 speed;
    public bool canMoveLeft;
    public bool canMoveRight;
    public int vertSpeed;

    public Player(Vector2 position, Texture2D tex)
    {
        pos = position;
        texture = tex;
        speed = new Vector2(1, 1);
        vertSpeed = 0;
        hitbox = new Rectangle((int) position.X, (int) position.Y, tex.Width, tex.Height);
        leftHitbox = new Rectangle((int) pos.X, (int) pos.Y, 1, tex.Height);
        topHitbox = new Rectangle((int) pos.X, (int) pos.Y, tex.Width, 1);
        bottomHitbox = new Rectangle((int) pos.X, (int) (pos.Y + tex.Height), tex.Width, 1);
        rightHitbox = new Rectangle();
        canMoveLeft = true;
        canMoveRight = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("The texture height is {0} and the bottomHitbox Y is {1}", tex.Height, bottomHitbox.Y);
    }
```

In the game, I move the Player using these methods I put in the same class:

```
public static void MovePlayerToVector(Player player, Vector2 newPos)
{
    player.pos = newPos;
    UpdateHitboxes(player);
}
```

However, as you can see, the method takes a Player object and changes the `pos` variable. Is there a way to make this into a method that extends the object?
For example, moving the player would look like this:

```
Player player = new Player(bla, bla);
player.MovePlayerToVector(new Vector2(1,1));
```

.. Instead of this:

```
Player player = new Player(bla, bla);
Player.MovePlayerToVector(player, new Vector2(1,1));
```

.. Which is quite inefficient.

I do not know what this is called and can't Google it. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make this into a method that extends the object?

Try

```
public void MovePlayerToVector(Vector2 newPos)
{
    pos = newPos;
    UpdateHitboxes(this);
}
```

instead of

```
public static void MovePlayerToVector(Player player, Vector2 newPos)
{
    player.pos = newPos;
    UpdateHitboxes(player);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance method rather than a class method i.e.

In the player class:

```
public void MoveToVector(Vector2 newPos)
{
    this.pos = newPos;
}
```

Then the following works without side effects.

```
Player player = new Player(bla, bla);
player.MoveToVector(new Vector2(1,1));
```

Also:

```
public Vector2 pos;
public Rectangle hitbox;
```

Make these private and encapsulate with methods or properties e.g.

```
private Vector2 pos;
private Rectangle hitbox;
```

Comment: I'll mark as answer in 10 min, site's giving me problems :(  
And thanks for the quick reply!